# Why my "Render" viewport shading just looks like Material preview??? even I add the Light point?

Tags: rendering

[image][image]

Why my "Render" viewport shading just looks like Material preview??? even I add the Light point? everything don't like render preview?

I have made sure that Scene Lights and Scene World are checked, so that isn't the problem:

[image: Scene]

Comment: Hi. I moved your image into your original question because it's a more fitting place. I also edited my answer to show another example. Maybe you'll find it helpful?

Comment: Not sure which step making wrong???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have "Scene Lights" and "Scene World" unchecked. If unchecked, the Material Preview lighting and reflections appear in your Render Preview:

[image: Scene]

This can also happen if you connect your materials directly to the material output without a shader, as seen below. If done this way, the material is considered "unshaded" and is thus unaffected by scene lights.

[image: Shaderless]

Comment: Thanks, I will go back to fix my notes, maybe I install the "Poliigon-material-converter" to messed up my notes.

Comment: Thanks Christopher!